# How can I read the data of a file using FileDialog?

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with reading the data inside a file using a FileDialog to load the file.
I've tried file.getFile() and it just returns the filename not the data inside it.

```
FileDialog f = new FileDialog(mainFrame, "Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
f.setDirectory("C:\\");
f.setVisible(true);
System.out.println(f.getFile());
```

Moreover whenever I want to pass (f) in a scanner it gives me an error

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
//Java Lang FileDialog cannot be converted to readable.
```

Comment: If you have the filename, you have enough to open & read from the file.

Comment: Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/ After that, read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Comment: Use the documentation;  it is your best friend.  f.getFile() [returns a String filename](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/FileDialog.html#getFile()).  The [Scanner constructor documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#constructor.summary) shows that you must pass a File, Path, InputStream, or Readable object, not a FileDialog or String.  (**Caution:** Do not pass a String directly;  that will cause the Scanner to read from the characters of the string instead of reading from a file.)

Answer (score -2):

One way to do that is to use this method - > getFiles() .Its Returns files that the user selects( File [] ).And after you can go through the file you want to read in several ways .
See here:
https://tutorialspoint.dev/language/java/different-ways-reading-text-file-java

Comment: That helped a lot! Passing getFiles() as a parameter for a new file object worked. Thank you.